# MS-Word bookmarks with VB script

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a classic ASP application which inserts some values into a word file using bookmarks. I can insert text on the bookmarks. The only problem is checkboxes, I have some checkboxes in document. I have created bookmarks on checkboxes. Can someone tell me how to tick the checkboxes through VB script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some way out for the problem,

Dim objCheckbox
Set objCheckbox = objDoc.FormFields("Name").CheckBox
objCheckbox.Value = True

Please suggest if you can give me some other solution.

Cheers.